# Make Pretty Url's for Custom CMS with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am making my own CMS for my social networking website. I'm facing a problem, I need to clean the url to make it pretty like facebook does.

URL Rewrite using HTACCESS

```
Urgly URL => www.domain.com/index.php?options=profile&id=393
Clean URL => www.domain.com/393
```

Currently am using this code below to remove inde.php?options from url

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?options=$0 [QSA,L]
```

I have searched Google and tired everything but it does not work for me. Something is weird...

please help am stuck really badly..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your rule+condition will match every request including images, scripts, stylesheets etc and will redirect it to index.php. I doubt that's what you want.

You can rather do it the other way around. If people visit your index.php or top domain name (eg. www.domain.com) do nothing.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Then you can rewrite all applicable requests (paths that doesn't exist) to index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php?options=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Add these rules+conditions to your .htaccess and see if it meets your requirements.